# What's an efficient data structure/technique for detecting overlapping rectangles?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I'm working on a dashboarding application and want to be able to quickly tell if a new widget overlaps any other and if so, which ones it overlaps. Each widget is a rectangle with a left, top, width, and height dimension. Is there an efficient data structure I can use or way to do this?

Comment: How many rectangles are you expecting to have?  I would think that for most useful cases, a simple array would suffice.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: Voted to reopen, as this was tagged javascript, and a python duplicate might not be appropriate.  Also that was an *m x n* problem and this is *1 x n*.  On the other hand, we need to OP to show more effort before answering.

Comment: Yeah, that was the right duplicate. The top answer barely mentions Python; this isn't really a language question.